# Display values in JSF table

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a Java object with 30 attributes. I populate the object from database. I want to display only values which are not empty.

```
<table>
    <col width="280"/><col width="130"/>

    <ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{TreeViewController.componentData}">

        <tr>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="componentStatsId" rendered="#{ud.componentStatsId != 0}"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <h:outputText value="#{ud.componentStatsId}" rendered="#{ud.componentStatsId != 0}"/>
            </td>
        </tr>

        .......... and 40 more table rows

    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

I tested to create simple JSF table with rows which are not rendered if the values are empty. But I noticed that if the values are empty I get tiny spaces:

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that would be the expected behavior from your code since is just preventing the rendering of the `<<h:outputText>` but not the `<tr>` nor `<td>` components.

To solve this, you should use `<ui:fragment>` and control the `<tr>` and `<td>` renderization using the `rendered` attribute:

```
<ui:repeat var="ud" value="#{TreeViewController.componentData}">
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{ud.componentStatsId != 0}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                componentStatsId
            </td>
            <td>
                #{ud.componentStatsId}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:fragment>
    <!-- .......... and 40 more table rows -->
    <ui:fragment rendered="#{ud.componentTypeId != 0}">
        <tr>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
            <td>
                ...
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ui:fragment>
</ui:repeat>
```

Comment: I have to place `ui:fragment` below `ui:repeat` only once or at the top of every table row?

Comment: The `<ui:fragment>` should be inside `<ui:repeat>`. Note that the `<ui:fragment>` will just help you to know if you should render (or not) the `<tr>` and `<td>`s